# What is the meaning of "is it me"?

Tags: meaning

I want know what  is the meaning of "is it me"

For example:

> is it me, or is it kind of noisy here?

Any ideas or insight would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I can't figure out why this question is getting so many downvotes. This is a fairly common construct. I can see why this would be tricky for a learner, and be very hard to figure out just by looking up words like "is" and "it" in a dictionary.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make it simpler,

> is it me, or is it kind of noisy here?

Can be rephrased to

> Does anyone else think it is kind of noisy here, or is it only me?

Basically you're asking if something (the noise in this example) is something other people are hearing as well or if you are the only one that does.

Comment: (+1) for a neat explanation. But, should it be ... _or is it only me_ in the second quote?

Comment: @Dawny33 correct. I missed that

Answer (score 4):

It is a shortened version of "is it *just* me".

With that phrase, you are asking whether you are the only one that considers the noise level too high, or whether it is noisy *for others* as well.